# Django test - 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' invalid keyword argument to test client

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

My Django unit tests have stopped working. Instantiating the Django test client now fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/my/app/tests.py", line 43, in setUp
    self.client = Client(HTTP_USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 367, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % kwargs.keys()[0])
TypeError: 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

They fail when I instantiate the Django test client.

```
from django.test.client import Client
...

class MyAppTestCase(TestCase):
    base_fixtures = ['fixtures.json']

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client(HTTP_USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0') # fails here
        self.setupSession()
        self.authenticateUser()
```

When I run python manage.py shell and enter the following, it works fine.

```
vagrant@lucid32:/var/www/mytraps.com/spensa$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.test.client import Client
>>> client = Client(HTTP_USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0')
>>>
```

Any thoughts on why it is chocking on the HTTP_USER_AGENT keyword?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

I had a model class named 'Client'. My models were imported after the django test Client class.

You can't fix stupid.